# How to make in post Parent page children page list nummbered

Tags: pages, wp-list-pages, child-pages

Parent page
veggies
Its children pages are
    carrots
    peas
    potato

How to put in post numbered list of Parent page?
Maybe better how to make same list to be ordered by date posted so some order can be managed by changing dates?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely certain what you're asking.
If you want to have the list of pages in an ordered list insted of unordered it should be simple:

```
echo '<ol>';
wp_list_pages( array( 'title_li' => null ) );
echo '</ol>';
```

However if what you're asking is to order it according to some parameter so that you can shuffle it around, it looks easiest to me to simply sort by page order like this:

```
wp_list_pages( array( 'sort_column'  => 'menu_order' ) );
```

This will sort the pages by page order which you can change yourself by editing a page. Alternatively, you mentioned to sort by date, you can use:

```
wp_list_pages( array( 'sort_column'  => 'post_date'  ) );
```

You can find all this here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages

Alternatively you might want to play with this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/page-list/